# Multiple anchor tags with same href on same page with fragment identifier not working

Tags: jquery, html

This is the weirdest thing - I have an html page with the following anchor tag which works perfectly.

```
<a href="index.php#contact">Contact</a>
```

Further down the page I have the same exact anchor tag...

```
<a href="index.php#contact">Contact</a>
```

The first one works, the second does not! Firebug console shows the following error message:

```
[11:52:23.927] Syntax error, unrecognized expression: nav a[href=index.php#contact] @ http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js:2
```

This is so strange! If I remove the fragment identifier (the #contact) portion of the href the link works however! Example:

```
<a href="index.php">Contact</a>
```

And using a differen fragment identifier does not work - Example:

```
<a href="index.php#abcdefg">Contact</a>
```

Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your jquery selector.
It seems that somewhere you are calling a jquery function like this one (or similar):

```
$('nav a[href=index.php#contact]');
```

To fix it, use this:

```
$('nav a[href="index.php#contact"]');
```